# constrain type of values of an object in Typescript

Tags: typescript, types

In typescript, how to I write the type signature for plain old javascript object that can have any key, but the values are always strings. For example, `{a:"foo"}`, `{b:"bar"}` are both valid values but `{a:[1,2,3]}` and `{b:3}` are not.

I want to be able to write something like

```js
let foo : {*: string} = {a: "foo"}
```

Currently, I am using `any` to achieve this, but that isn't as precise as I would like.

Comment: If you don't care how many keys there are, you want an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types): `{[k: string]: string}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an index signature to state that all values will be a string...

```
type Example = { [key: string]: string };
```

Example:

```
type Example = { [key: string]: string };

const a: Example = {
    "anything": "any string", // ok
    anotherkey: "a string", // ok
    thirdKey: 1 // Error
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are looking at a `enum` definition for the values of your properties.

I think you can declare it something like:

```
let foo: { [k: string]: 'foo' | 'bar' | 'type'};

foo.a = 'bar';
foo.d = 'type';
foo.q = 'bar';
foo.c = 'let'; // shows as not assignable
```

You can see it in [this typescript fiddle](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=let%20foo%3A%20%7B%20%5Bk%3A%20string%5D%3A%20'foo'%20%7C%20'bar'%20%7C%20'type'%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afoo.a%20%3D%20'bar'%3B%0D%0Afoo.d%20%3D%20'type'%3B%0D%0Afoo.q%20%3D%20'bar'%3B%0D%0Afoo.c%20%3D%20'let'%3B%0D%0A)